# Can I apply for a secured credit card in the USA as a non-resident (currently adjusting status)?

Tags: usa, credit

I am thinking of getting a secured credit card as per reading [this](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/252/851) on the stack.

My question is will I get one as a K-1 visa holder who has filed to Adjust Status to a Permanent Resident (Green Card)? I don't have my Green Card yet, I estimate it will take many more months to process.

I already have a checking and savings account with the bank I plan to apply for the secured credit card with an SSN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have a Social Security Number you should be able to apply for a secured credit card.

The applications from various banks:

- [US Bank](https://www.usbank.com/credit-cards/secured-card.html)
- [Bank of America](https://www.bankofamerica.com/credit-cards/products/secured-credit-card.go)
- [Wells Fargo](https://www.wellsfargo.com/credit-cards/secured/)

Do not require you to be a Green Card holder to provide you with credit.  They do use your SSN to get credit reports on you to determine your creditworthiness so given that you haven't established credit history in the US your credit limit and security deposit may be affected by this but there is nothing that prevents a bank, which is a private entity from taking a risk and giving you credit.

Comment: Seems like you need a checking account with them.

Comment: @vagish You already have an account with someone, I just gave you some examples.  You can check with your bank if they have the same...

Comment: My checking account is with a credit union. They require me to be a minimum of a green card holder to give me a secured card.

Comment: You can just as easily open an account in a bank.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I got unsecured (once my credit was good enough) credit cards, a car loan and a mortgage before adjusting to permanent resident status (and a couple of years before applying to adjust).